# Filter from gridview just reload, not pjax. Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

I have a basic gridview with Pajax established. It makes the ajax request but often carries out a reload. It always happens the second time it is filtered.

**Controller**

```php
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new PersonSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```php
<?php

use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;

?>
<div class="auth-user-index">

    <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'pjax-users-gridview']); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'identification_number',
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

When you filter for the first time the parameters are corrected, the request is **XHR**. But the second time the request is **Document** and reload the page

Comment: add complete code the columns that you are filtering need to be added here

Comment: With this same code it does not work